# google batch translate with glossary give an error

Tags: google-translate, google-apis-explorer

As i follow the link [usingglossary](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/glossary#use_glossaries) and [batchtranslate](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/batch-translation#batch-request), and  [batchTranslateText api](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations/batchTranslateText) say glossaries should define like this.

```
glossaries:map (key: string, value: object (TranslateTextGlossaryConfig))
```

i want to use google batch translate with glossary,but always get error`TypeError: 'TranslateTextGlossaryConfig' object is not iterable`, my glossary is Equivalent term.Can any one give me a clue? i use python as demo code here:

```
    glossary_config = translate.TranslateTextGlossaryConfig(glossary=glossary,ignore_case=True)
    glossaries=map("th",(glossary_config))
    operation = client.batch_translate_text(
        request={
            "parent": parent,
            "source_language_code": sourcefrom,
            "target_language_codes": [targetto],  # Up to 10 language codes here.
            "input_configs": input_configs,
            "output_config": output_config,
            "glossaries": glossaries
        }
    )
```

Comment: i think i got the answer here https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/samples/translate-v3-batch-translate-text-with-glossary

Comment: glossaries = {"ja": glossary_config}  # glossaries, should be define like this.

Comment: But why it will output two files?one is glossary_translations.txt and the other is translations.txt
why this happen? Can I only output glossary translation file? Will translator charge me twice? https://github.com/googleapis/python-translate/issues/155#issue-886782720